# What does acceleration in kilometer per hour per second mean?

Tags: acceleration, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

What does the statement a body is accelerating **10 km / hr per second** means? I have always heard a body accelerating 10 km/sec square?

Comment: 1 hour = 3600 seconds.

Comment: So it means 10 km / 3600 sec x sec or 10 km per 3600 sec square OR 10 km / hr square?

Comment: What is the difference between sec x sec and sec squared?

Comment: Its same just expanded to show how its is sec squared - 10 km / hr per sec with 1 hour = 3600 sec then 10 kn / hr per sec = 10 km / 3600 sec sec ?

Comment: Am I correct in deduction 10 km / hr per sec  = 10 km / hr square - it means accelerating at 10 km per hour?

Comment: The way to think about acceleration is, for example: 10 km/hr/s = your speed increases by 10 km/hr every second. So, if I'm not moving initially, one second later I'll be traveling 10km/hr. At two seconds, I'd be moving 20km/hr and so on.

Comment: @David You should post that as an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: This non-standard way of expressing acceleration involves "mixed" units.  It's best to convert to $m/s^2$, as shown in some of the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a=\frac{10\,\text{km}}{1 \text{hour}\times 1\text{s}}$$
$$a=\frac{10\,\text{km}}{3600\,\text{s}\times 1\,\text{s}}$$
$$a=\frac{10000\,\text{m}}{3600\,\text{s}^2}$$
$$a=2.777\,\text{ms}^{-2}$$

Comment: Why the downvote??

Answer (score 2):

The way to think about acceleration is, for example: 10 km/hr/s = your speed increases by 10 km/hr every second. So, if I'm not moving initially, one second later I'll be traveling 10km/hr. At two seconds, I'd be moving 20km/hr and so on.

Answer (score 0):

10 kilometers per hour is minutely less than 2.8 meters per second (2.777), therefore an acceleration of 10 kilometers per hour per second is equal to almost 2.8 meters per second per second acceleration.